# Cassandra custom system path in linux

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm install cassandra at linux SO by rpm

```
[root ~]$ rpm -Uvh cassandra-3.11.2-1.noarch.rpm
warning: cassandra-3.11.2-1.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fe4b2bda: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
1:cassandra              ########################################### [100%]
```

Default install directory is `/var/lib/cassandra/`

```
[root ~]$ ls /var/lib/cassandra/
commitlog  data  hints  saved_caches
```

How can I change this directory to install at `/home/cassandra` ?

Comment: you want to change the commitlog, data, hints, saved_caches directory location or the cassandra binaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/var/lib/cassandra is the default Cassandra home directory where, as you can see, commitlog, data hints and saved_caches are stored. To change these you need to change each of their config parameters in the cassandra.yaml file:

- hints_directory
- data_file_directories
- commitlog_directory
- saved_caches_directory